# Create a CFUNCTYPE dynamically at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

When using ctypes in Python, is it possible to create a CFUNCTYPE with a specific signature, eg

```
ctypes.CFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
```

dynamically rather than hardcoded at runtime? Using Python 3.7 on Windows

The code I currently have creates the string, eg, "ctypes.CFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)" then uses eval to create the object.

I'd like to be able to construct a CFUNCTYPE object without having to use eval. The point of doing it dynamically is that I don't know the signature for the CFUNCTYPe unless runtime.

Comment: What does your input look like?  That would help define what you mean by "dynamically".  You certainly can do `a=c_void_p; b=c_char_p;f=CFUNCTYPE(a,b)` but I doubt that's what you want.  Show the code you currently have, if any.

Comment: The code I currently have creates the string, eg, "ctypes.CFUNCTYPE (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)" then uses eval to create the object. I'd like to be able to construct a CFUNCTYPE object without having to use eval. The point of doingit dynamically is that I don't know the signature for the CFUNCTYPe unless runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question was downvoted, its a perfectly legitimate question and received a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible example which returns an instance of a `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE` from a string:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes
import re


re_cfunc = re.compile(r"ctypes\.CFUNCTYPE\((.+)\)")

def functype_str_parser(functype_str: str):
    match = re_cfunc.match(functype_str)
    if not match:
        return None

    types_str = match.group(1)  # e.g. "ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p"
    argtypes = list()
    restype = None
    for i, type_str in enumerate(types_str.split(",")):
        module, ctypes_type_str = type_str.split(".")  # e.g. ["ctypes", "c_void_p"]
        ctype_type = getattr(ctypes, ctypes_type_str)  # e.g. <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
        if i == 0:
            # the first one is the return type of the CFUNCTYPE
            restype = ctype_type
        else:
            argtypes.append(ctype_type)

    return ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)"
    print(f"Input: {s}")
    cfunc_type = functype_str_parser(s)
    if cfunc_type is None:
        # the string couldn't be parsed
        exit(-1)
    print(f"result: '{cfunc_type}'; type: {type(cfunc_type)}")

    # these are protected attributes and should not be used; the following code demonstrates the parsing was correct.
    print(f"restype: {cfunc_type._restype_}")
    for i, argtype in enumerate(cfunc_type._argtypes_):
        print(f"Argtype #{i}: {cfunc_type._argtypes_[i]}")
```

Output:

```
Input: ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p)
result: '<class 'ctypes.CFUNCTYPE.<locals>.CFunctionType'>'; type: <class '_ctypes.PyCFuncPtrType'>
restype: <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
Argtype #0: <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>
```